# Error "no match operator[]" al introducir datos en un map dentro de un objeto

Tags: c++, map, object

Estoy tratando de guardar datos en un mapa dentro de un objeto y recibo este error en var[name]=val y en var[name]:

> no match operator[]

**header**

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class Calculator{
public: 
    void addVal(string name, int val);
    int getVal(string name);
private:
    int memory;
    map <string,int>* var;
};
```

**cpp**

```
#include "Calculator.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

Calculator::Calculator():
memory(0), var(new map<string, int>)
{}
void Calculator::addVal(string name, int val){

    var[name]=val;

}

int Calculator::getVal(string name){
    return var[name];

}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Calculator{
private:
    map <string,int>* var;
//                  ^
};
```

Fíjate en ese asterisco... gracias a él, `var` es un puntero. Si el acceso al mapa se hace a través de un puntero tendrías que escribir algo tal que:

```
void Calculator::addVal(string name, int val){
    (*var)[name]=val;
}
```

Aunque también podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
void Calculator::addVal(string name, int val){
    var->operator[](name)=val;
}
```

Aun así todo indica a que el error en tu caso es el uso del asterisco. Bórralo y entonces podrás acceder a los métodos del mapa sin problemas.

Como nota final, procura no hacer uso de `using namespace` en los ficheros de cabecera. En programas más grandes te puede dar problemas.

Tu código corregido luciría así:

```
class Calculator{
public: 
    void addVal(string name, int val);
    int getVal(string name);
private:
    int memory;
    map <string,int> var;
};

Calculator::Calculator()
  : memory(0)
{ }
void Calculator::addVal(string name, int val){
  var[name]=val;
}

int Calculator::getVal(string name){
  return var[name];
}
```

Comment: Al quitar el * me manda error en la definicion del mapa var(new map<string, int>) "No se encontro una funcion coincidente" como lo definiria?. Gracias

Comment: Es que si usas el mapa por valor no hace falta llamar a `new`. He editado la respuesta para enseñarte el código corregido.

Comment: Ohhh vale muchas gracias =D

Answer (score 1):

Si lo compilas, te da los errores:

- Las funciones miembro `addVal` y `getVal` no tienen el retorno en la declaración mas si la tienen en la definición, así que el compilador no sabe identificarlas.
- `getVal` está declarado con los parámetro `(string, name)` y definido con el parámetro `(string name)`.
- Defines el constructor de `Calculator` pero no lo declaras.
- `var` es un **puntero** no un objeto, para usarlo deberías primero [des-referenciar](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operador_de_desreferencia) y luego usar: `(*var)[name] = val` y `return (*var)[name]`.

Por cierto, no borras `var` en el destructor.

¿Has intentado compilar o **entender** los errores? Parecen bastante autoexplicativos.

Comment: Perdon al pasar el codigo, me equivoque en los retornos y en la declaracion de parametros, pero esas 2 estan bien en el codigo original, si no defino el mapa como puntero me manda error en la inicializacion del cpp y no se como hacerla en este cazo

Comment: Si haces que el mapa no sea puntero, no puedes crearlo mediante `new` en el constructor... normal que te de error. Intenta **entender** los errores; si no los entiendes por estar en inglés, pasalos por el traductor de Google o dinos exáctamente que error tienes para que te podamos ayudar.